# Can I get proper typings when assigning an object of an extended type to object of base type

Tags: typescript

I have these interfaces:

```
interface BasicThing {
    someType: string
    property0: string
}
interface SpecificThing1 extends BasicThing {
    someType: 'special1'
    property1: number
}
interface SpecificThing2 extends BasicThing {
    someType: 'special2'
    color: string
}
```

and in my code I have this variable

```
let myThing: BasicThing
```

to which I will assign either `SpecificThing1` or `SpecificThing2` (or others) later on.

Now if I want a `SpecificThing1` assigned, I could just do:

```
myThing = {
    someType:  'special1',
    property0: 'asdf',
    property1:  42
} as SpecificThing1
```

But doing it this way, I'll only get typing errors if I'd assign a wrong type to the properties (like `property1: '42' // string is not compatible with number`), but *missing* properties won't raise any errors at all:

```
myThing = {
    someType:  'special1',
    property0: 'asdf'
    // property1 is missing here, but no typing errors
} as SpecificThing1
```

One hackish way to solve this is to do:

```
myThing = ((): SpecificThing1 => {
    return {
        someType: 'special1',
        property0: 'asdf',
        // property1: 123 // Now we get the typing error: 'property1 is missing in type...'
    }
})()
```

But that doesn't look good, and to create a scope just to get correct typings of that object doesn't feel right.

Is it possible to assign a type to an object when creating it and not just on the recieving end? Shouldn't this be possible to do in a more elegant way?

Comment: Of course it's not going to warn you when you're assigning to a variable typed as BasicThing, because it's not missing any part of *that* interface (which is all consumers could use anyway). If you want to check you're creating a SpecificThing1 right, assign to a variable that *actually has that type*.

Comment: Yes, by assigning to another (temporary) variable would be another way to do it, but that feels hashish as well, don't you agree?

Comment: I don't agree. If you want an object to meet a specific interface you're going to have to define that somewhere. It's unclear what you're actually trying to achieve here, or why this behaviour surprised you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a union type instead of the base type. The effect is pretty much the same, you will have access to the common properties which are the properties in `BaseThing` (although you may get other common properties if derived types have them)

```
let d2: SpecificThing1 | SpecificThing2 = {
    someType: 'special1',
    property0: '0',
    property1: 1
}
let based: BasicThing = d2;
```

Another solution is to define an intermediate variable and never directly assign the variable of the base type

```
let o: SpecificThing1 = {
    someType: 'special1',
    property0: '0',
    property1: 1
}, d: BasicThing = o;
```

Another option would be to define a helper function, where you can specify the generic parameter, and the checks will be performed as expected:

```
const literal = <T>(o: T) => o;

let d: BasicThing = literal<SpecificThing1>({
    someType: 'special1',
    property0: '0',
    property1: 1
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, your last example is pretty much what I was after, thanks!